# Twitter Authenticated API access

Tags: api, twitter

I want my user to get authenticated just once and then I will save the required detials for the user, as I want to use the API for the mentions, hot tweets, popular tweets,etc.
Is their any way I can directly access the API functions without using the authentication process of login to twitter again when I want to use this functions.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is already like that. You ask for authentication **only for once** then store access token of that user. Whenever you send requests to Twitter on behalf of that user, you will pass that token. This is how it is done unless the user revokes your access..